# What would be the best practice for retaining a state on refresh in React/Flux?

Tags: javascript, flux

This is something I typically solved using local storage or cookies in angular. I'm assuming a similar process would be appropriate in Flux. Would I use localStorage within my store to retain state? Or would I make a fresh set of requests on refresh? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage or cookies would work fine, yes. In your store, you can use local storage or something like Firebase to keep data -- and then cache it in a JavaScript object. That way, when asked for data, the store can check to see if it has data in memory and, if not, check against the more permanent storage mechanism of local storage, Firebase -- or just going back to the server if need be.